# ios - unable to replicate the search path setting in the Target->Build Settngs

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios6, urbanairship.com

I am working on creating push notifications with UrbanAirship. I am working with this https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started:+iOS:+Push

and I am on the section titled "Build Settings"

They have a screenshot like this:

[image]

but when I try to do it in my xCode, I am only able to set it this way:

[image]

So I am not able to have the setting appear right after the line "Header search paths" but rather in its sections for debug and release.

What is the difference from the way I did it to the way that is described in the documentation? And how can I make it appear the way it is in the documentation?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check out the screenshot provided by UA more closely you'll see that next to the Header Search Paths there is a disclosure arrow pointing right. 
If you could click on this arrow it would expand the entries to show the Debug and Release phases just as you are seeing in Xcode.
Looks to me like you're doing everything correctly :)

Comment: thanks :) My concern was that in their screen shot, on the main line right after the "header search paths" it says "Airship" but in my version it just says <multiple values> and I am not sure what is the implication of that.

Comment: Yes I can see that can be weird. Don't worry it's literally indicating that there's more than one entry. It would be nice if it checked to see if both were the same and then display as the UA screenshot shows. Thats probably just a variation in Xcode versions.